# php Узнать определена ли константа.?

Tags: php

Определена константа

```
define("TEST_MODE",true);
```

как определить была ли она определена?

```
if (isset($var)) {
    echo "Эта переменная определена, поэтому меня и напечатали.";
}
```

isset определяет переменную. `isset(TEST_MODE)` не работает,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[defined](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.defined.php)**  - Проверяет существование указанной именованной константы

```
if (defined('TEST_MODE')) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
define ('MY_CONSTANT',  36);

if (defined('MY_CONSTANT'))
{
    echo "Constant is defined";
}
else
{
    echo "Constant is not defined";
}
?>
```